APs in sumsets of exponential growing sequences
I posted this initially on SE, but after I didn't found a particular reference on it, I decided it would be more appropriate to post it here. A friend shared this observation with me and I thought that it was interesting

Let $F_k = (s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n, \dots )$ be the increasing sequence of numbers that are representable as a sum of $k$ Fibonacci numbers (not necessarily distinct), show that there's no arithmetic progression of length $10^k$ in this sequence.

Some approach that failed are showing that the gap is increasing, this is false and you can certainly have a lot consecutive numbers (in fact checking for the case $k=3$ the large APs are from consecutive numbers that are contained there), but I was certain that in any, say $10^k$, there will be a gap bigger than any number inside of it, my initial idea to show this was considering the representation of the number $n = \sum_{i=1}a_iF_{b_i}$ where $\sum a_i = k$ and $F_{b_i}$ are Fibonacci numbers and $b_1 < b_2 < \cdots < b_n$, then adding $1$ at a time, so that we can conclude the next term of the sequence is $\sum_{i=2}a_iF_{b_i} + (a_1 - 1)F_{b_1} + F_{b_1 + 1}$ but this can't really works due to the fact that I'll never be able to assure that the next term will not just be another sum of Fibonacci numbers with same arrangement. Even if it worked the grow of the sequence could be as slow or quick as I may impose. The problem can be generalized by changing the Fibonacci numbers to any exponential-like sequence like powers of $2$ or numbers such that $s_n \sim a^n$ for some positive real $a > 1$, and I imagine that the problem is true in that case. Another thing is that it is quite possible that I can change $10$ to any positive number bigger than $1$ (in the case of Fibonacci numbers) and for big enough term in the sequence this will be true.
I did some stupid coding to check the problem by using the first $20$ Fibonacci numbers and using this.
with open("fibonacci.txt", 'r') as file:
        fibonacci_numbers = [int(line.strip()) for line in file if line.strip().isdigit()]
fibonacci_sums = set()

for i in fibonacci_numbers:
    for j in fibonacci_numbers:
            for k in fibonacci_numbers:
                        fibonacci_sums.add(i + j + k)

fibonacci_sums = sorted(fibonacci_sums)

n = len(fibonacci_sums)

def longestAPSubsequence(arr, n):
    ans = 0 # Initialize the length of the longest subsequence to 0
    for i in range(n - 1): # Loop through all pairs of elements in the array
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            diff = arr[j] - arr[i] # Calculate the difference between the two elements
            len = 2 # Initialize the length of the current subsequence to 2
            curr = arr[j] # Set the current element to the second element of the subsequence
            for k in range(j + 1, n): # Loop through the remaining elements of the array
                if arr[k] - curr == diff: # Check if the next element is part of the subsequence
                    len += 1 # Increment the length of the subsequence
                    curr = arr[k] # Set the current element to the next element of the subsequence
            ans = max(ans, len) # Update the length of the longest subsequence if the current subsequence is longer
    return ans # Return the length of the longest subsequence
 
print(longestAPSubsequence(fibonacci_sums, n))

In the fibonacci.txt I copied and pasted the first few Fibonacci numbers, this list can be used for that.
Any comments or references on this problem are welcome.

First of all, every positive integer has a unique Zeckendorf representation, and this is the representation as a sum of the minimal number of Fibonacci numbers. So all terms in the progression should have Zeckendorf representations with at most $k$ summands.
Let $\ell_k$ be hemaximal lengthof an AP composed of such numbers. Take a progression of $\ell=\ell_k$ such numbers $x_1!\dots,x_\ell$. At least $(\ell-1)/\phi$ of them lie on the segment $[x_n/\phi,x_\ell]$. This measn that the largest terms in their Zeckendorf representations may attain only two different values, so at least $(\ell-1)/(2\phi)$ of those terms should be equal.  Subtracting that common term, we get an AP of at least $(\ell-1)/(2\phi)$ numbers with at most $k-1$ terms in their representations. Hence
$$
  \ell_k\leq 1+2\phi\ell_{k-1},
$$
which yields what you need.

Thanks! I think this also generalizes for my other questions.
